# Unable to retrieve metadata and multiplicity is not valid role in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it necessary to specify all the required relationship for mapping in the fluent API? 
I have four classes in my model. To be specific: they are => BUS, PASSENGER, ROUTE, RESERVATION.

```
public class Bus
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Route")]
    public int RouteId { get; set; }
    ..............

    [ForeignKey("RouteId")]
    public virtual Route Route{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

 public class Passenger
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .........
    .........
    public virtual Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BusId { get; set; }
    public int PassengerId { get; set; }
    .................
    ..............

    [ForeignKey("BusId")]
    public virtual Bus Bus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PassengerId")]
    public virtual Passenger Passenger { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    .............
    .............
    public virtual ICollection<Bus> Busses { get; set; }
}
```

I have modeled my DbContext File as below:

```
 public class TicketContext: DbContext
 {
    public TicketContext()
        : base("TicketDbContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Bus> Busses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Passenger> Passengers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Route> Routes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention 
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        //configure the primary key for "Bus" ENTITY
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bus>()
            .HasKey(p=>p.Id);

        //configure one to many relationship between "Bus" and "Passenger" ENTITY 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bus>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Reservations)
            .WithRequired(p => p.Bus);


        //configure the primary key for "Passenger" ENTITY
        modelBuilder.Entity<Passenger>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        //configure one to one relationship between "Passenger" and "Reservation" ENTITY

        modelBuilder.Entity<Passenger>()
            .HasRequired(i => i.Reservation)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(i => i.Passenger);

        //configure the primary key for "Reservation" ENTITY
        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        //configure the primary key for "Route" ENTITY
        modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
            .HasKey(p => p.Id);

        //configure one to many relationship between "Route" and "Bus" ENTITY

        modelBuilder.Entity<Route>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Busses)
            .WithOptional(r => r.Route);

    }
}
```

After that when I wanted to create a controller for Bus with model class Bus and with the DbContext specified visual studio gives me the following error. 
[image]

What have I done wrong here? Do I have to specify relationship for all entity?